# Angularjs: how to use ng-repeat while skipping a given $index value still reaching —and limiting to— 3 results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My search engine must display 3 photos max, plus one master photo included in the photos list of the data source.

I have this code snippet with the first table column picking the appropriate photo (diag.photoId-1), while the 3 next, taking the 3 first photos form the data source.
Things works great except when the dig.photoId-1 is one of the 3 first photos (I skip it, but then I miss one).

Any simple way to handle this a part from creating specific or changing the data source?

```
        <tr ng-repeat="diag in accidentSearchResults">
            <td class="key textOutline"
                style="background-image:url(rsc/accident/thumb/{{accidents[diag.accidentId].id}}/{{accidents[diag.accidentId].photos[diag.photoId-1].file}}.thumb.jpg)">
                <div class="cut-arrow-right"></div>
                <p>{{accidents[diag.accidentId].displayName}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="notScrollable">
                    <div
                        class="disk" 
                        ng-repeat="p in accidents[diag.accidentId].photos | limitTo: 3"
                        ng-if="$index != diag.photoId-1"
                        ng-click="openAccidentPage(diag.accidentId)"
                        style="background-image:url(rsc/accident/thumb/{{accidents[diag.accidentId].id}}/{{p.file}}.thumb.jpg)"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, forget about it, my bulb just lit… "limitTo: diag.photoId-1<3?4:3" just does the job.

Comment: You can also write a filter for that.